# Can’t Polytheists abuse 9:6 by repeatedly seeking protection?

Tags: fiqh, tafseer, jihad

Allah said:

> And if anyone of the polytheists seek your protection then grant him protection until he hears (the) Words of Allah. Then escort him (to) his place of safety. That (is) because they (are) a people (who) do not know. 
> **[ Corpus Quran 9:6 ]**

Lets say we are waging Jihad against the kuffar. Since Allah **commanded** us to grant protection to anyone  from
The polytheists who seeks it then cant they just abuse this verse as a way of repeatedly escaping death?

i.e Whenever the mushrik is about to be killed he requests protection, and the muslim is obligated to grant him it.

Comment: The verse says "until he hears (the) Words of Allah," so it appears to be a one time thing or at least until you're sure. Also, it's not unknown for people to have tried to seek protection by doing things like claiming to be Muslim when they're about to be killed. There is a famous hadith mentioning one incident. We are told only to judge by what they say and not try to determine if they're being hypocritical.

Comment: @TheZ it also says “if anyone of the polytheisys..” so it shouldn’t matter if he is a polytheist who sought protection before

Comment: It doesn't matter which polytheist he is, but what matters is the length or lack of length of the time of protection. If he's already heard the Quran, "until he hears the words of Allah" implies protection does not even start. It ends immediately.

Comment: @TheZ Yeah that makes sense to me but is there a sunnah which demonstrates this or a tafsir that says this

Answer (score -1):

We must consider that the Message of the Quran is a message Muhammad (p.b.u.h) received in his situation. Some Ahadith indicate that the reception of this message was not purely unilateral but the prophet also asked for advice in particular situations. It is important for our understanding to know in which situation he received the advice.

From the context, it is quite clear that this was when he was in war with the Arabic polytheists who refused his message and fought against the prophet (p.b.u.h).

The aim of this war was not to kill those on the other side but to save those who received the Message and to make the others convert and abandon polytheism. The Quran Message is to save those who had been fighting on the other side and seeked mercy when they were captives or had given up the fight.

In that situation, it was meant to be giving a chance to  them once, it may be given a second time but without a clear obligation to do so. The first time is obliged, the second chance isn't.

Now, what does this mean today?

In most cases, we are not in the situation that polytheists have waged a war against the believers. If the situation is not the same, it is too short to understand the advice given in this situation as a general rule in any situation.

At present, we see two situations where Muslims are aggressed and wronged by - rather atheist than polytheist - disbelievers; China's government agressing the Uigur people and Myanmar's government aggression to the Rohinja people. In both cases, the victims receive large moral support even beyond the Muslim society but no military support. At least in the case of China, a military action would be likely to create a great disaster, so that rather the Message Jesus (p.b.u.h) received in his situation not to fight against the Romans (who were polytheists and not righteous rulers either) may be closer to the situation.

If you think that you are encouraged or even obliged to do a private fight against polytheists under any circumstance, please refrain. This is not the Message of the Quran: Allah is Eternal but His Advice is given to those who received it in the situation in that they were. We do not have any commandment to wage war against peaceful polytheists to captivate them and force them to convert. It's an evil trick of the evil spirit to suggest people to "follow" the word of the Holy One and do evil to discredit those who believe. The abuse of the Word of Allah would be on the side of the evil one, so beware!

Comment: Brother why are u giving me apologetics

Comment: @Jarir cause I was wondering in what context someone fears abuse on this base.